# Python matplotlib/pandas fails with "OverflowError: value too large to convert to npy_uint32"

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, snakemake

I am trying to run this [variant call pipeline](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-gatk-variant-calling) with 144 samples so the resulting files are quite big. I managed to get it almost to the end, but the last rule (plots_stats) fails with `OverflowError: value too large to convert to npy_uint32`. This is a [Python script](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-gatk-variant-calling/blob/main/workflow/scripts/plot-depths.py), that plots from a gzipped tsv file. I guess, I just have to many rows in my calls.tsv.gzto be handled. The complete error log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/[PATH]/workflow_var_calling/.snakemake/scripts/tmp10j_ba31.plot-depths.py", line 16, in <module>
    sample_info = calls.loc[:, samples].stack([0, 1]).unstack().reset_index(1, drop=False)
  File "/[PATH]/workflow_var_calling/.snakemake/conda/5e32b1f022a698680d2667be14f8a58a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2899, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
  File "/[PATH]/workflow_var_calling/.snakemake/conda/5e32b1f022a698680d2667be14f8a58a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 501, in unstack
    constructor=obj._constructor_expanddim)
  File "/[PATH]/workflow_var_calling/.snakemake/conda/5e32b1f022a698680d2667be14f8a58a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.index = index.remove_unused_levels()
  File "/[PATH]/workflow_var_calling/.snakemake/conda/5e32b1f022a698680d2667be14f8a58a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py", line 1494, in remove_unused_levels
    uniques = algos.unique(lab)
  File "/[PATH]/workflow_var_calling/.snakemake/conda/5e32b1f022a698680d2667be14f8a58a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 367, in unique
    table = htable(len(values))
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 937, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.__cinit__
OverflowError: value too large to convert to npy_uint32
```

any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a memory limit is hit, I would try running it on a machine with more RAM.

Comment: I am running this on a slurm cluster and allocated 512GB of RAM. Before exiting the job only consumed around 340GB. Python also exits with exit code 1. This is not the exit code for a memory error, is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Didn't read it carefully enough.